# PHP OOP with mysqli class

Tags: php, class, properties, mysqli

Okay, I have searched everywhere for the answer, but instead of any real answers, I figured this one would be a decent ask for anyone out there:

My class' member function that uses mysqli's "mysqli_query" member function:

```
    class mysqlidbconn extends mysqli {

        protected $conn;  //Or private $conn;  
        function dbconnect(){
            $localHost = false;
            $link = new mysqli("server","database username","password","databasename")   
               or ($die = true);
            if ($link->connect_error){
                die("Database selection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
            }else{
                $this->conn = $link;
            }

         }
```

And the member function in question for executing insert/update/delete/truncate queries:

```
    // To Execute Sql Query with no return result
    function xQuery($sql) {
        $this->conn->query($sql) or die("MySQL Query Execute Error: " . 
            $this->invDBConn->errorno . "<br>" . $this->conn->error . "<br>" . $sql 
            . "<br>");
    }
```

When doing inserts and truncates on a table, the above situation works perfectly with $conn initialized as a PRIVATE or PROTECTED member variable of class mysqlidbconn, as exampled in the code below using the mysqlidbconn class, no error is generated, but also, no update takes place to the mysql table:

```
  <?php
      require('path to php file containing mysqlidbconn class');
      $msqli = new mysqlidbconn;
      $msqli->dbconnect();

      //This works
      $sqlinsert = "insert into foo (foo_id, foo_field1...) values ('foo_id value',  
          'foo_field1 value',...);    
      $msqli->xQuery($sqlinsert);  

      //As does this
      $sqltruncate = "truncate foo"; 
      $msqli->xQuery($sqltruncate);

      //But the below does not work, giving no error, result, etc.
      $sqlupdate = "update foo set foo_field1='another foo_field1 value'";
      $msqli->xQuery($sqlupdate);
```

However, when the class is written with the $conn variable as PUBLIC, the above

```
    $sqlupdate = "update foo set foo_field1='another foo_field1 value'";
    $msqli->xQuery($sqlupdate);
```

updates the table successfully.

What is going on here OOP-wise that I'm missing when writing my mysqlidbconn class?

Thanks for your help and my apologies on any code that did not post according to forum rules.

Comment: A couple things:  1. you need to assign your MySQLi object to a variable in order to use it.  In other words, `$blah = new mysqli(/* args */);`  2. What is `$die = true;` supposed to do?  `$die` the custom variable you just made IS NOT the same as `die` the script killing statement.  To be honest, I've never seen much point in extending MySQLi.  It's already a class.  Your `xQuery()` method isn't appreciably different than the existing `query()` method, which you actually delegate to.

Comment: on your 1) -- fixed, during my post I simply did not mention $link's initializing to new mysqli(...).  on your 2)  $die is processed in the following if-else statement.  I am aware that $die != die().  3)  Yes, you are correct, but I wanted to stick with a member variable as mysqli within my own class since there are several other functions related to mysqli that I use that are not available across all versions of mysql, i.e. loading xml files is different for <v5.2, etc., so I have custom functions written there for that purpose. --- and yes I could dispense with query()

Comment: SQJ injection much? You should rather use parameterized queries actually. If you do, disregard my comment.

Comment: @sinni800 -- they get escaped on the way in.  The question emphasizes why update queries silently do not update a table (without any error) when $conn is protected or private, but update the table when $conn is public.

Comment: @user1793027 Okay, that's why I pointed it out as a comment. But yeah, I had the same thing happening. I don't remember how I solved it...

Comment: @sinni800 -- Thanks for pointing it out.  I solved it (not the essence of my question above, but the problem of update queries silently not updating through mysqli::query()) by making $conn public, but I guess to clarify, I wanna know why when it's public, but not private or protected.  I suspect it has something to do with query returning something, but does it not already return at least a boolean (true/false)?  The answer is yes, but something funky having to do with update queries.

Comment: @user1793027 The only change you did wa smaking it public? I'll just put this into "strange cases of PHP".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$link = new mysqli("server","database username","password","databasename") or
             ($die = true);


// To Execute Sql Query with no return result
     function xQuery($sql) {
         $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
         if(!empty($result))
         {
             return $result->fetch_assoc();
         } else {
             return $this->conn->errno;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Yeah I actually had that in my original code, so no go on an answer here -- edited accordingly.  This would have actually thrown an error and the script would have never ran.  My apologies.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I am to see you through an interpreter in English, I'm trying to learn English

Comment: No problem, Luo -- you did great and pointed out something I had missed.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing OOP-wise and a question is not a real one, as it is caused by a mere measurement error, like many hundreds of thousands questions here.

No OOP-related thing can intefere with SQL, making some queries run and some not. YET, many PHP users have difficulties with update queries, updating already updated data, or checking result in wrong database etc.